# Plotting p-value in normal distribution (in R)?

Tags: r, statistics, normal-distribution, p-value

i am a beginner when it comes to statistics. I am trying to display p-value in a plot, or rather, to add an abline to display it on the plot of normal distribution. Currently I am doing it like this.

```
pVal = 0.04
abline(v=qnorm(pVal/2))
```

I am however not sure if this is correct. I would like to visualize whether p-value is above/below alpha (in this case lets say alpha=0.05).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to spend some time with a basic R tutorial. I'm not sure what you want, but maybe this is close:

```
x <- seq(-3, 3, length.out=100)
plot(x, dnorm(x), typ="l")
alpha <- .05
a <- c(-1, 1) * qnorm(alpha/2)
pVal <- 0.04
v <- c(-1, 1) * qnorm(pVal/2)
abline(v=a)
abline(v=v, lty=2)
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: Probably easier with `curve(dnorm(x), -3, 3)` without the need to code a `seq` first.